# How to create custom error page in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I read the reference from the following url

[Customized 404 error page in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835504/customized-404-error-page-in-spring-boot)
and its working.

In the above document they used .HTML pages. But i need .jsp pages.

```
src/
+- main/
   +- java/
   +- resources/
       +- public/
           +- error/
           |   +- 404.html
```

ie. 404.html to 404.jsp

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You just need to configure

```
InternalViewResolver
```

as with .jsp extension.

**Edit:**

Please check the below sample code.

```
private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX = "your/jsp/location";
private static final String VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX = ".jsp";

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix(VIEW_RESOLVER_PREFIX);
    viewResolver.setSuffix(VIEW_RESOLVER_SUFFIX);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me a sample configuration? Is any changes in 'application.properties'?

Comment: I already configured in 'application.properites'.  spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/Views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp. Error pages can either be static JSP

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

You need first to configure spring boot to use jsp as it is not offered out-of-the-box. In maven pom.xml, add the following dependencies:

```
    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

In application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp
```

The way I have configured it, the .jsp files then need to be in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp folder so create it if needed.
Let's say I then create a file src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.jsp. To access it from my controller, I simply refer to it as

```
return "error/404";
```

since spring boot will automatically add the view prefix and suffix for me.